# Network connection from old application to SQL Server 2008 R2 lost once in a while

Tags: sql-server, network, virtualisation

I have put this question on serverfault.com as well, but since the problem concerns connecting to SQL Server, I will also put it here.

We are trying to migrate an Axapta 2.5 database from SQL Server 2000 to 2008 R2. We are testing performance etc. on the new server, but once in a while, these two events are thrown on the Axapta server:

> Object Server SandBOX: The database reported (session 11 (CSS)):
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Communication link failure. The SQL
>   statement was: ""

and

> Object Server SandBOX: Fatal system condition - quitting for restart
>   due to lost database connection.

after which all clients have to reconnect.

The Axapta 2.5 server is a virtual server (VMWare) running Windows 2003 SP2. 
Info from vSphere:

- VM Version: 7
- CPU: 1 vCPU
- Memory: 1024 MB
- VMNetwork: VMXNet 3

The SQL Server is also a virtual server (VMWare) running Windows 2012 R2.
Info from vSphere:

- VM Version: 8
- CPU: 4 vCPU
- Memory: 73728 MB
- VMNetwork: VMXNet 3

There are no traces of an error in either the event log on the SQL Server or in the SQL Server Logs.

When searching the internet for a solution, I only found one with this exact problem, and it had no answer *([how to troubleshoot sql 2008 dropping connections on sqlservercentral.com](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/33693/how-to-troubleshoot-sql-2008-dropping-connections.html))*. I mostly see suggestions around the virtual network adapter or settings on the virtual server, for more or less similar problems.
I'm probably forgetting a lot of information, but I'm actually a DBA, so bear with me.

I know very little of virtual machines and network. Thanks for your help.
Could anyone point me in a direction with this issue?

Comment: Make sure you dont have these problems on sql. 2000. Some times when people are testing to se if an upgrade is possible, they find problems which has been there all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Axapta 2.5 was not supported on SQL Server 2005 or later versions so you are out of your depth there. To support later version of the database engine you will need to update the axapta application itself. 2.5 predates SQL Server 2005 by years: http://everything.explained.today/Microsoft_Dynamics_AX/

Any problems you have with incorrect statements are most probably due to the axapta server getting confused over the database version, you could try to change compatability level to 8.0 but I would recommend that you contact an Axapta certified partner and migrate to newer version of the application

Answer (score 0):

"Communication Link Failure" Occurs when the client loses connection to the SQL server. There can be a ton of reasons behind this incurring. Here are some tips

1. Check the DBMS Settings in AxConfig. Try to introduce KeepAlive Setting.
2. SQL Server does not forcefully close connection without logging an error. Check the logs
3. Run Profiler to see what actually happens with the connection.
4. See if you can switch to OLEDB instead of ODBC for better performance
5. Keep the compatibility level to 8.0
6. You can establish a telnet session between the servers. If the telnet link is dropped then you are most probably facing a network issue.
7. Use [TCPViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) to monitor what actually happens with your connection on port 1433.

Good luck :)